# Change basis from Bloch states to "Bloch factor states"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

The Bloch states $\{|\Psi_{n,\vec{k}}\rangle\}$ form a basis and fulfill the completeness relation 
$$
\mathbb{1}=\sum_{n\vec{k}}|\Psi_{n\vec{k}}\rangle\langle\Psi_{n\vec{k}}|.
$$
Using the completeness relation we can write an operator $\hat{A}$ in terms of the Bloch state basis
$$
\hat{A}=\mathbb{1}\hat{A}\mathbb{1}=\sum_{nn'}\sum_{\vec{k}\vec{k}'}|\Psi_{n\vec{k}}\rangle\langle\Psi_{n'\vec{k}'}|\,A^{nn'}_{\vec{k}\vec{k}'},
$$
where the matrix elements are given by $A^{nn'}_{\vec{k}\vec{k}'}=\langle\Psi_{n\vec{k}}|\hat{A}|\Psi_{n'\vec{k}'}\rangle$. According to the Bloch theorem, the Bloch wave functions $\langle\vec{r}|\Psi_{n\vec{k}}\rangle=\Psi_{n\vec{k}}(\vec{r})$ can be written as

$$
\Psi_{n\vec{k}}(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}u_{n\vec{k}}(\vec{r}),
$$
where $\langle\vec{r}|u_{n \vec{k}}\rangle=u_{n\vec{k}}(\vec{r})$ is the lattice periodic Bloch factor.
Now, I would like to write $\hat{A}$ in terms of the "Bloch factor states" $\{|u_{n \vec{k}}\rangle\}$ , but I do not know if the Bloch factor states fulfill a completeness relation similiar to the one written above for the Bloch states. I have seen people using $|\Psi_{n\vec{k}}\rangle=e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}|u_{n\vec{k}}\rangle$ in which case
$$
\mathbb{1}=\sum_{n\vec{k}}|\Psi_{n\vec{k}}\rangle\langle\Psi_{n\vec{k}}|=\sum_{n\vec{k}}e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}|u_{n\vec{k}}\rangle\langle u_{n\vec{k}}|e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}=\sum_{n\vec{k}}|u_{n\vec{k}}\rangle\langle u_{n\vec{k}}|,
$$
would follow. However, I don't feel confident using $|\Psi_{n\vec{k}}\rangle=e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}|u_{n\vec{k}}\rangle$ since the left-hand side of this equation does not depend on $\vec{r}$, while the right-hand side does. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: What is the definition of Bloch factor state $|u_{n\vec{k}}\rangle$ that you are using? I haven't seen this notation elsewhere, so just wanted to confirm

Comment: The $|u_{n\vec{k}}\rangle$ 's are eigenfunctions of the Bloch Hamiltonian $H(\vec{k})$ that is often given in condensed matter physics. (see for example Eq. (1) in https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys1270.pdf). @ArkyaChatterjee

Comment: What you call Bloch factors have the same periodicity of the lattice. So they cannot form a complete basis set because every function expressed with their linear combination is also periodic!

Comment: @fra_pero That makes sense. Thank you very much for your explanation.

Comment: @fra_pero I don't see how that argument is correct. For example, we know that Fourier expansions are complete (http://web.mit.edu/jorloff/www/18.03-esg/notes/fourier-complete.pdf), yet all of the contributing functions are periodic. This looks like a counter-example to your claim.

Comment: @Arkya Fourier expansions, while periodic, have differing periodicities (albeit are harmonics of each other). Thus, this is not an obstacle to completeness. Bloch functions on the other hand all have the exact same periodicity - that of the lattice. Hence they can’t be complete